# Is there a way to manually remove a method in the generated Swagger UI?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, swagger-ui, spring-data-rest, springfox

I used Springboot + Springfox + Spring Data Rest to generate my APIs and documentation.

It works great, except in SDR you can programmatically remove a REST method say "PUT" for a specific Entity.

```
 ExposureConfiguration config = restConfig.getExposureConfiguration();

        config.forDomainType(User.class).disablePutForCreation();
        config.withItemExposure((metadata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(HttpMethod.PUT));
```

But Springfox/Swagger won't pick this up and still shows the method as available in the documentation.

Is there a way to tell Springfox/Swagger that it's now removed?

Answer (score 0):

I hide method programmatically by spring-fox annotation:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Description here.", httpMethod = "PUT", hidden = true)
```

Comment: Added where? Some context around where exactly you added that may make your answer more useful.